# Calling a Jframe from another jframe using less Object creation

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a Jframe that contains a button that upon clicking opens the next jframe(let it be A)

Jframe A constructor contains the code like:

```
setVisible(true);
setSize(343,34);
```

i have put the following code to do inside Jbutton actionListener:

```
new A();
```

Now, i have ten jframes that too have a button with same functionality.
I think this approach is not proper as everytime i click ,a new Object of A is made.
Is there some other solution To this Problem ?

Comment: If you want only one instance of A, just make it a singleton class.

Comment: @Bala R. It doesn't need to be a singleton class. It can just be a member variable, the frame being visible or not.

Answer (score 2):

A possible simplistic solution could be the following.

In your Jbutton actionListener:

```
new ActionListener {
    private JFrame jFrame = null;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (jFrame == null) {
            jFrame = new A();
        }
        jframe.setVisable(true);
    }
}
```

I would then remove the code from the A() constructor that makes that frame visible on construction.  That is just a personal coding preference.  I never liked when a Frame would appear at construction time.

Of course this is a very simplistic solution.  You could really get into a more complex solution quickly.  You could have mediators that listen specifically to that particular JButton and then have a strategy for showing that new Frame etc...  It really depends on how coupled you want your code.

**EDIT**

More slightly more complex example that doesn't use an anonymous inner class...

```
public void AMediator implements ActionListener {
    JFrame jFrame = null;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (jFrame == null) {
            jFrame = new A();
        }
        jFrame.setVisable(true);
        jFrame.bringToTheFront():  // Not sure this method exists, but it might be worth it to bring this frame forward even if it is already visible.
    }
}
```

You would then need to register the above mediator with each button that you want to open the A JFrame instance.

There are many ways of registering this mediator:
- Use a main class that will wire up all your components together.
- Use Spring's dependency injection.
- Use a centralized service that is accessible by many different services.
- Others?

That way, you will only have one mediator (instead of many anonymous ActionListener inner classes).

Comment: i want to elimiate the statement new A().is there some other way to do this task.

Comment: @ProgramME Somewhere you have to construct `A`. Even when injecting with Spring you probably should have a helper method to ensure construction in the EDT. But you could create jFrame A in the constructor / initializer of the parent.

Comment: As @extraneon stated at some point you have to call the constructor of your A JFrame.  You just can't make something out of nothing.  You will have to construct it at some point.  That is where the more complex solutions come in to play.  The solution provided above is fairly hightly coupled.  Using mediators to listen for that event could lower the coupling while still keeping your code highly cohesive.  If you need something more substantial, just ask.

Comment: ok,i have to create it one time but how to solve the problem when its made again and again in differnt frames in order to call the frame A